# Symmetric Mean Absolute Error

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions

I'm currently working in a ML problem, in which I have to predict the amount of returned quantities of some sold products. I'm working on some sort of weighted error metric which not only takes into account the deviation with respect to the *actual returned quantity*, but also the quantity of sold units of a given product.

The reasoning behind this is that a bad prediction of the returned amount for a product of which many units where sold, should worsen *more* the error metric of that particular product than that of a product with fewer units sold.

One simple option would be to work with some *mean* error, such as the *MAE*,

${MAE} ={\frac {\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left|y_{i}-x_{i}\right|}{n}}={\frac {\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left|e_{i}\right|}{n}}$

However as mentioned, I'd like an error measure for each product. Perhaps something like *SMAPE* or *MAPE* but using some weight factor? Perhaps using a linear combination of the quantity of sold units as weight?

Any guidance or suggestions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the problem, I don't think you actually *care* about the absolute difference at all. If you can rework the model to output the 'rate of returns' $\hat{R}$ for the product sales $S$, such that:

$$R_{true}*S = Y <=> R_{true} = \frac{Y}{S}$$

Where $Y$ represents the actual returned amount, you can define your loss as $L(x)=\frac{\hat{R_x}}{R_{true}}$.

The minimum loss is reached when $\hat{R}=R_{true}$, so setting $R_{true}$ to 1 - because why would we rescale it arbitrarily? - shows we can simply optimize $(\hat{R}-1)$ to be as close to zero as possible according to some norm (absolute difference (so, MAE loss), sum of squares (MSE loss), whatever).

You can then easily recover the absolute returned amount by multiplying your model's output by the sales of the item. This actually seems much neater, because you're no longer tightly coupled with the actual figures, which could vary wildly, and you probably get much friendlier gradients to boot.

Comment: My question was going more in the direction of an appropriate error metric (hence simply on the stage of understanding the results) for this problem, rather than reformulating the problem changing the dependent variable. However, this makes a lot of sense and is very helpful, thanks a lot @jkm